# ¿Por qué 'probabilidad' es 0 cuando t es igual a -1?

Tags: c++, loops

La consola me muestra los 10 números y por alguna razón solo cuando 't' es un número par, me da el resultado correcto. Cuando t es 1, me da 0 en vez de 0.3297 y cuando es un número impar, me da el mismo número que el anterior.

```
int y=7;
float probabilidad,e=2.71828,a;

for(int t=-1;t>=-10;t--){
a=pow(e,t/2);
probabilidad = 1 - a;
gotoxy(5,y);
cout << probabilidad;
y++;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cuando t es 1, me da 0 en vez de 0.3297 y cuando es un número impar, me da el mismo número que el anterior.

El problema es que en esta línea

```
a=pow(e,t/2)
```

`t` es de tipo `int`, luego `t/2` no va a poder generar parte decimal:

```
t=-1 => t/2 =  0 <-- da -0.5 pero la parte decimal desaparece
t=-2 => t/2 = -1
t=-3 => t/2 = -1 <-- da -1.5
t=-4 => t/2 = -2
t=-5 => t/2 = -2 <-- da -2.5
...
```

La solución pasa por forzar a que esa división sea entre tipos `float`:

```
a=pow(e,t/2.0f)
```